# Does PDFBox executes javascript and executables?

Tags: security, pdf, pdfbox

I want to use PDFBox for convert pdf to images. I have following questions ->

- Does PDFBox looks for executables and javascript while rendering
- If it identifies executables, does it ignore the script/executable or it doesn't render at all?

Is there an official documentation where I can read about security related questions and how PDFBox rendering works?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by executables but PDFBox does not execute any JavaScript embedded in the PDF form fields. However, a conforming viewer *should* create appearances for any calculated fields so unless you are modifying the field values in PDFBox prior to rendering, the appearance of the field should be correct and that is what PDFBox will render.

Comment: There is no documentation "how rendering works", nor is there a documentation of "security related questions" and JavaScript code is ignored. Open a file with PDFDebugger and then look what you get.